# How to get the error shows in web console using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logging, error-handling, elk

I want to log all of my error that happen in my website especially on the front end. And the important thing I wanna do is to log all of the error or warning that appears on my website console (F12). How can I get all of that error/warnings using vanilla JavaScript? Thank you.

Comment: You want to save your errors to a .log file on your computer hard drive ?

Comment: Yes, I wanna save all of my console throw to .log file in my computer storage. All of the types. such as error, warning or normal log.

Comment: Well, you can't unless you do a POST request or use web sockets to send them back to the back-end. A front end application cannot directly write to the hard drive of a computer.

Comment: @DekaThomas are you specifically seeking for a method that involves the ELK stack? Is that why you have added 'elk' as a tag here?

Comment: @Sandun yes, i'm looking for implementing my project using ELK to do some logs